# C++ STL containers, 'under the bonnet'?

Tags: c++, stl

what would be the best way to learn what actually happens with the STL containers? I presume just programming wouldnt be enough. Are there any books specifically aimed at this?

Comment: Why wouldn't programming be enough? If you know the C++ language, and you know the behavior of each container, it there are few surprises in the STL implementation.

Comment: @jalf: A typical STL implementation uses a number of non-trivial Template Metaprogramming tricks. Just consider the history of `std::auto_ptr`; arguably that surprised even the C++ experts.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This book is quite good, even if maybe it does not go deep enough in the details as you would like: [The C++ Standard Library: A Tutorial and Reference](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0201379260)

Answer (score 2):

[Generic Programming and the STL: Using and Extending the C++ Standard Template Library](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0201309564)

Answer (score 2):

The best way to figure out what's happening 'under the bonnet' is to actually look under the hood and find the [source code](http://gcc.gnu.org/viewcvs/trunk/libstdc%2B%2B-v3/) :)

Otherwise just read the documentation. I recommend [this site](http://www.sgi.com/tech/stl/), or [this book](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0201379260).

Comment: I don’t think so. The libstd source code is a horrible, horrible mess in at least the two most popular implementations (i.e. g++’s and Dinkumware’s). STLPort’s may be more readable, but I doubt it, if only due to the usage of double underscores all over the place to avoid name clashes.

Answer (score 2):

Stephan T. Lavavej is currently doing [video lectures](http://channel9.msdn.com/shows/Going+Deep/C9-Lectures-Introduction-to-STL-with-Stephan-T-Lavavej/) about the STL.

Answer (score 0):

There are books dedicated for C++ STL. You could try one of those.

Answer (score 0):

Found the below resources quite useful:
May not be up-to-date but [SGI Stl Programmer's Guide](http://www.sgi.com/tech/stl/stl_introduction.html). It has a good conceptual overview of the STL library.
Source code navigation:
I've used the [Free Evaluation Source Insight Code Browser](http://www.sourceinsight.com/eval.html) which allows to jump all around the source code from sgi's stl code.
Alternatively you can try out [LXR](http://lxr.linux.no/+trees), [doxygen](http://www.doxygen.nl), [Ctags](http://ctags.sourceforge.net).

Videos:
[STL Tutorial by Stephen Lavavej](http://www.eventhelix.com/realtimemantra/object_oriented/stl-tutorial.htm)
[Going Deep into STL with Stephen Lavavej](http://channel9.msdn.com/Shows/Going+Deep/C9-Lectures-Stephan-T-Lavavej-Standard-Template-Library-STL-2-of-n)
[Inside STL with Stepan Lavavej](http://channel9.msdn.com/shows/Going+Deep/VC-10-Stephan-T-Lavavej-and-Damien-Watkins-Inside-STL)
[C++0x Features in VC10](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/vcblog/archive/2009/02/03/rvalue-references-c-0x-features-in-vc10-part-2.aspx)

See Also:
[C++ Templates - The Complete Guide by Nicolai Josuttis](http://www.josuttis.com/tmplbook/)
[C++ Template Meta-Programming - Concepts, Tools and Techniques](http://www.boostpro.com/mplbook)
[Inside the C++ Object Model by Stanley Lippman](http://my.safaribooksonline.com/book/programming/cplusplus/0201834545)